# Downloaded Facebook archive doesn't contain all messages

Tags: facebook, export

The downloaded Facebook archive has a messages.htm file in it with my Facebook messages. But I know for sure that a lot of them are missing. My top conversation with about 65k messages has exactly 10000 messages in the messages.htm file. At the end of this conversation it says:

```
<div class="warning">We were unable to download the remainder of this conversation.</div>
```

In the past you had the ability to download an extended archive of your Facebook data but that doesn't seem to exist anymore. Is that right?

So how can I get the messages.htm file containing *all* my Facebook messages?

Answer (score 4):

I've been dying to figure out how to do this, and I've already tried messing with the Facebook API to obtain my message history with a single person - without success. After 11000 messages I couldn't obtain further messages.

What worked for me is [this Facebook app](https://apps.facebook.com/redonemymessages/), which downloads the message history for one person at a time. It's slow, and it doesn't get all messages but only those for one conversation, but it's as good as it gets. Their privacy policy promises that they delete your messages from their servers immediately after you've downloaded them, and that they don't do anything with your data other than provide you with your download.

Whether or not you try it is up to you - don't make me responsible if the people behind this app steal your secret pictures or your credit card data from a conversation.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure whether I should trust them though.

Comment: That's ultimately up to you. You could try messaging them to ask what queries they use to collect the messages and then collect the messages yourself, if you're apt enough. If you do, please be sure to share your findings!

Comment: The link to the Facebook app is broken.